# JAVA: Read char from String to a certain char

Tags: java

Is there a method or way to read and keep reading chars from a string, putting them in a new string until there is a certain char.
Keep reading from < to > but no further.
Thankx

Comment: Do you really need to read these characters one at a time?

Comment: From `<` to `>`? Aren't you reinventing a XML/HTML parser?

Comment: @BalusC, I was thinking the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You will need:

- the method `String.charAt(int)`
- the `+` operator (or the method `String.concat`, or, if performance matters, the class `StringBuilder`)
- the `for` statement
- and perhaps an `if`-statement with a `break` statement

The statements and operators are explained in the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), and the method in the api javadoc.

(And no, I will not provide an implementation, since you would learn little by copying it)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write a utility that does that

```
public class StringUtil {

    public static String copy(String str, char startChar, char endChar) {
        int startPos = str.indexOf(startChar);
        int endPos = str.lastIndexOf(endChar);

        if (endPos < startPos) {
            throw new RuntimeException("endPos < startPos");
        }

        char[] dest = new char[endPos - startPos + 1];
        str.getChars(startPos, endPos, dest, 0);

        return new String(dest);
    }
};
```

**PS** Untested....

---

Alternatively, you can

```
String result = str.substring(startPos, endPos + 1); //If you want to include the ">" tag.
```

Comment: You had me up until the `char[]` line.  That line and the ones afterward seem like an awful lot of work for recreating `String.substring`.

Comment: And, `lastIndexOf()` may not be what you need. This will fail on e.g. `text<foo>text</foo>text` and return `<foo>text</foo>` instead of `<foo>`.

Comment: @BalusC, agreed, the SO can use `str.indexOf(endChar, startPos + 1)` to find the closest closing bracket. I'm assuming that `str = "<foo>"`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want but it will give you the desired string.

```
 String desiredString="<Hello>".split("[<>]")[1];
```